# Why is code behavior different in release & debug mode?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, coreclr

Consider the following code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ar = new double[]
    {
        100
    };

    FillTo(ref ar, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ar.Select(a => a.ToString()).ToArray()));
}

public static void FillTo(ref double[] dd, int N)
{
    if (dd.Length >= N)
        return;

    double[] Old = dd;
    double d = double.NaN;
    if (Old.Length > 0)
        d = Old[0];

    dd = new double[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < Old.Length; i++)
    {
        dd[N - Old.Length + i] = Old[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N - Old.Length; i++)
        dd[i] = d;
}
```

The result in Debug mode is: 100,100,100,100,100.
But in Release mode it is: 100,100,100,100,0.

What is happening?

It was tested using .NET framework 4.7.1 and .NET Core 2.0.0.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio (or the compiler) do you use?

Comment: Repro; adding a `Console.WriteLine(i);` into the final loop (`dd[i] = d;`) "fixes" it, which suggests a compiler bug or JIT bug; looking into the IL...

Comment: @Styxxy, tested on vs2015, 2017 and targeted every .net framework >= 4.5

Comment: Definitely a bug. It also disappears if you remove `if (dd.Length >= N) return;`, which may be a simpler repro.

Comment: @MarcGravell even adding Thread.Sleep(1) fixes it in release mode.

Comment: And I for some reason cannot reproduce - always outputs "100,100,100,100,100" in release mode for me.

Comment: @Evk: what platform and .NET version? This is likely a jitter bug and thus heavily dependent on what bits you've got.

Comment: @Evk on this pc tested on vs2015, 2017 and targeted every .net framework >= 4.5, but i got different behavior on other machine by targeting .net framework >= 4.7

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have .NET 4.7 installed (not 4.7.1 or 4.7.2) and tried to target 4.5,4.6,4.7.

Comment: No repro; I have .NET 4.7 installed on my machine. Both Debug and Release mode output same values (5 times 100). Same like @Evk

Comment: Version targeted isn't usually relevant (they'll all use the same JIT compiler), only the installed framework version is. I have 4.7.1, so this may be a regression.

Comment: Repro using .NET Core 2.

Comment: Only reproducible for me if targeted as x64

Comment: Unable to reproduce on net47, AnyCPU or x86 or x64 ConsoleApp VS2017

Comment: It is not surprising that once the comparison is apples-to-apples, x64 codegen for .Net Framework and .Net Core has similar performance, since (by default) it is the essentially the same jit generating code. It would be interesting to compare the performance of .Net Framework x86 codegen with .Net Core's x86 codegen (which is using RyuJit since 2.0). There are still cases out there where the older jit (aka Jit32) knows a few tricks that RyuJit does not. And if you find any such cases, please make sure to open issues for them over on the CoreCLR repo.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This appears to be a JIT bug; I've  tested with:

```
// ... existing code unchanged
for (int i = 0; i < N - Old.Length; i++)
{
    // Console.WriteLine(i); // <== comment/uncomment this line
    dd[i] = d;
}
```

and adding the `Console.WriteLine(i)` fixes it. The only IL change is:

```
// ...
L_0040: ldc.i4.0 
L_0041: stloc.3 
L_0042: br.s L_004d
L_0044: ldarg.0 
L_0045: ldind.ref 
L_0046: ldloc.3 
L_0047: ldloc.1 
L_0048: stelem.r8 
L_0049: ldloc.3 
L_004a: ldc.i4.1 
L_004b: add 
L_004c: stloc.3 
L_004d: ldloc.3 
L_004e: ldarg.1 
L_004f: ldloc.0 
L_0050: ldlen 
L_0051: conv.i4 
L_0052: sub 
L_0053: blt.s L_0044
L_0055: ret
```

vs

```
// ...
L_0040: ldc.i4.0 
L_0041: stloc.3 
L_0042: br.s L_0053
L_0044: ldloc.3 
L_0045: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
L_004a: ldarg.0 
L_004b: ldind.ref 
L_004c: ldloc.3 
L_004d: ldloc.1 
L_004e: stelem.r8 
L_004f: ldloc.3 
L_0050: ldc.i4.1 
L_0051: add 
L_0052: stloc.3 
L_0053: ldloc.3 
L_0054: ldarg.1 
L_0055: ldloc.0 
L_0056: ldlen 
L_0057: conv.i4 
L_0058: sub 
L_0059: blt.s L_0044
L_005b: ret
```

which looks exactly right (the only difference is the extra `ldloc.3` and `call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)`, and a different but equivalent target for `br.s`).

It'll need a JIT fix, I suspect.

Environment:

- `Environment.Version`: 4.0.30319.42000
- `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`
- VS: 15.5.0 Preview 5.0
- `dotnet --version`: 2.1.1

Comment: Then where to report the bug?

Comment: @AshkanNourzadeh I only see it on .net core - is that what you're targeting? this changes where to file the bug, so is important

Comment: I see it on .NET full 4.7.1 as well, so if this isn't a RyuJIT bug I'll eat my hat.

Comment: @JeroenMostert interesting; I don't repro on 4.7 - I don't have 4.7.1. locally AFAIK, unless it is an over-the-top install

Comment: I could not reproduce, installed .NET 4.7.1 and can reproduce now.

Comment: @MarcGravell .Net framework 4.7.1 and .net Core 2.0.0

Comment: @AshkanNourzadeh I would probably log it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) to be honest, emphasising that people believe it to be a RyuJIT error

Answer (score 6):

It's an assembly error indeed. x64, .net 4.7.1, release build.

disassembly:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < N - Old.Length; i++)
00007FF942690ADD  xor         eax,eax  
            for(int i = 0; i < N - Old.Length; i++)
00007FF942690ADF  mov         ebx,esi  
00007FF942690AE1  sub         ebx,ebp  
00007FF942690AE3  test        ebx,ebx  
00007FF942690AE5  jle         00007FF942690AFF  
                dd[i] = d;
00007FF942690AE7  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdi]  
00007FF942690AEA  cmp         eax,dword ptr [rdx+8]  
00007FF942690AED  jae         00007FF942690B11  
00007FF942690AEF  movsxd      rcx,eax  
00007FF942690AF2  vmovsd      qword ptr [rdx+rcx*8+10h],xmm6  
            for(int i = 0; i < N - Old.Length; i++)
00007FF942690AF9  inc         eax  
00007FF942690AFB  cmp         ebx,eax  
00007FF942690AFD  jg          00007FF942690AE7  
00007FF942690AFF  vmovaps     xmm6,xmmword ptr [rsp+20h]  
00007FF942690B06  add         rsp,30h  
00007FF942690B0A  pop         rbx  
00007FF942690B0B  pop         rbp  
00007FF942690B0C  pop         rsi  
00007FF942690B0D  pop         rdi  
00007FF942690B0E  pop         r14  
00007FF942690B10  ret
```

The issue is at address 00007FF942690AFD, the jg 00007FF942690AE7. It jumps back if ebx (which contains 4, the loop end value) is bigger (jg) than eax, the value i. This fails when it's 4 of course, so it doesn't write the last element in the array.

It fails, because it inc's i's register value (eax, at 0x00007FF942690AF9), and then checks it with 4, but it still has to write that value. It's a bit hard to pinpoint where exactly the issue is located, as it looks like it might be the result of the optimization of (N-Old.Length), as the debug build contains that code, but the release build precalculates that. So that's for the jit people to fix ;)

Comment: One of these days I need to carve out some time to learn assembly / CPU opcodes. Perhaps naively I keep thinking "meh, I can read and write IL - I should be able to grok it" - but I just never get around to it :)

Comment: x64/x86 isn't the greatest assembly language to start with tho ;) It has so many opcodes, I once read there's noone alive who knows them all. Not sure if that's true, but it's not that easy to read it at first. Though it does use a few simple conventions, like the [], the destination before source part and what these registers all mean (al is 8bit part of rax, eax is 32bit part of rax etc). You can step through it in vs tho, which should teach you the essentials. I'm sure you pick it up quickly as you already know IL opcodes ;)